# Migrate wordpress site from subdomain to top domain

Tags: wordpress, url, amazon-ec2, subdomain, bitnami

I'm running wordpress bitnami website on an ec2 instance, via a subdomain. I want the site to point to the top domain. I have tried to figure this out technically but no success. i.e. from new.example.com to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (default-domain)

Comment: Is the top domain already pointing to the machine? Did you configure the DNS for it?

Comment: @Michield'Hont ,at first I tried to change A values(IP address) route-53 top domain to point to the machine, however the site did not show images/some content was missing out, I tried to check wordpress site URLs and site name, but fields were not editable, then I had to revert back to running on subdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add an A record for the main domain that points to the machine and then configure the domain in wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://DOMAIN/');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://DOMAIN/');
```

Replacing DOMAIN with the actual domain.

Comment: I changed the A record via the host-zone, as well as the site URLs